# HTACCESS rewrite, select after a specific character

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a 301 redirect for some old URLs. An example of an old URL:

```
http://www.example.com/forum/news/555-subject-test
```

I want to redirect this to:
     http://www.example.com/news/subject-test

I have this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /forum/news/(.*)-(.*) /news/$1
```

However this redirects it to http://www.example.com/forum/news/test

Any ideas how I can fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forum/news/[0-9]+-(.+)$ /news/$1
```

rather than:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /forum/news/(.*)-(.*) /news/$1
```

Comment: Thank you! But i'm redirected to following url http://www.example.com/news/555-. ***EDIT** Sorry, I didn't copy your whole solution. Looks like its working! Thank you.